# How to search for "remote only" jobs?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, search

I've seen that some jobs are "remote" without office location, how can I search for them? I tried to leave the location field empty, and select "allows remote", but in the results I get also companies with a "physical" office location

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible. But...

*Can you explain what's leading you to want to search for remote jobs with no physical location?*  This is the first request we've heard of this kind, but if you can help us understand the use case a bit better, we may be able to implement something similar in the future.

Comment: Looking at the various remote postings, I see some caveats such as time-zones,working permits etc, that led me to the impression that offices without physical location are better organized for the remote working exigences (I must add that I don't have any kind of experience with remote jobs)

Comment: I'll add my two cents here: I live in a rural area and am not interested in moving or commuting. If I were to take a new job (not actively interested at the moment), I would only be looking for remote opportunities. (Technically, I would also be looking for local, physical locations; however, given my location, those are exceedingly unlikely to be posted on SO.) (Found this question linked from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348054/set-up-job-match-preferences-to-only-full-remote?cb=1) )

Comment: When looking for job offers I don't want to relocate from my small town in France, so remote only (out of few travel per year) would be my choice, I'm not interested in "remote possible 2 days per week" at all. (Just realized I found this because of the new answer)

Comment: This feature request has been here for four years. It has been sufficiently explained in the comments. So I guess it might help you understand the use case and you might be able to implement something similar in the present :)

Answer (score -1):

Currently you can search only for "Allows remote" and it's as easy as selecting a box. This isn't as specific as you want to. If a firm has an office and allows remote, then it will also appear in the search results.

---

### Mobile

[image: Stack remote jobs mobile]

---

### Desktop

[image: Stack remote jobs desktop]