# Set up job match preferences to only full remote

Tags: support, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

How can I tell potential employers I am only interested in full remote jobs?

In my "Job match preferences" I can check the box saying "Willing to work remotely", but I assume that only shows my willingness to possibly work remotely instead of it being a requirement from my side.

I already just got a message from a potential employer with only the buttons: "I'm interested" and "I'm not interested", however I don't even know if it is an actual remote job or not. So I cannot even choose whether I am interested.

1. Is there a way to make clear I am only looking for remote jobs?
2. How do I handle the current message from the potential employer?

<sub><sub>I just told the potential employer "I am interested" because I replied to the message asking for clarification about the remote possibilities. Doesn't look optimal having to do this for every employer coming to me me thinks.</sub></sub>

Comment: Very interesting feature request if it's not already available

Comment: This should be implemented from start, it's not only interesting, but basic feature. I struggled with the same and in the end searched the job on different sites :(

Comment: It should be a range rather than a boolean.  For example, 0-5% is remote allowed once a month, 0-40% two days a week, etc. Companies with no office but meet occasionally would be 95-100.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We don't currently collect "full time remote" data, but we have gotten recurring feedback that this would be helpful. Will keep this in mind if we build out our remote data/features.

Comment: This is a MUST have!!! Please add this!!!!

Answer (score 20):

That's an interesting request, I'll make sure to bring it up.

When you received a message from the potential employer, you also got a link to the position they were recruiting for, right? you should be able to see the listing and determine if it's a remote position or not.

Not ideal, I know... but we'll discuss about implementing your suggestion :)

Thanks!

Comment: Many employers have (IMO) misused the "remote" flag.  They consider the position "remote" if they allow you to work from home one day a month if your dog dies.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316527/can-the-jobs-careers-team-explain-to-employers-the-purpose-of-the-remote-optio?rq=1

Comment: @silencedmessage that's not exactly what this question is about ;) employers should use Remote when they allow people working 100% remotely. We explain that to them, so if you find any listings where that's not the case, please flag the listing and we'll reach out to the particular employer.

Comment: That's why it's a comment to your answer and not an answer?  Your answer says that for now, you could look at the posting to see if it's listed as remote.  My comment says that the remote flag has proven to not be reliable.  I've flagged a few in the past, but I gave up on it because it was a never ending battle.

Comment: Also, it would be better to make it mandatory for employers to specify timezone details for remote jobs e.g. US/EU/UK/Asia or how many hours time difference they can accept. I think currently some employers do specify this but not all of them; a lot of them still just remote possible but without details.