# New filter feature for remote jobs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, filtering

Basically there are jobs that offer the possibility to work remotely sometimes, and others are 100% remote jobs. 
It would be great to be able to filter them separately, maybe a new category or perk 100% remote.

Comment: Completely agree.  A long time annoyance of mine that truly remote jobs can't be filtered.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348054/set-up-job-match-preferences-to-only-full-remote

Answer (score 12):

Yes, please.

I've been bitten by this before. Listing says "allows remote" then I get a note asking about location and saying that they're looking for someone local who can work from home but "come in if needed", or in one case didn't find this out until the first phone interview that they wanted someone in the office 2 or 3 times a week! "What if you were only required to come in once a week?" (the office is 200+ miles away from me).

That listing seems to not have the `remote` marker anymore, but under perks it still lists "Culture of flexible working, from home, office, or anywhere you like".